# Reloading datasource in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm just getting started with iOS development and since I'm quite accustomed with C#, I have decided to give Xamarin iOS a go. So far, I've been very happy with it since the performance is just great and it utilizes my favorite language. :-)

However, I've stumbled upon an issue and I can't figure out how to fix it. I'm trying to recreate a Tinder like swipe-effect with a set of images. All is working fine, I've added a click event to the image, prevented it from swiping once the end of the datasource is reached etc.

For all this, I'm using the Xamarin iOS component XCardView, which is based on ZLSwipeableView for iOS. Now I also want to implement a refresh function, just to get a different set of images to display / swipe. However, I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xcardview - Here you can see the sample code, which I am using for the most part. The only change I made is that I made a List of images and I keep track of the currently displayed image, so I know which image (index) to get next. So, every time the method NextCardForCardView gets called, I get the next image in the list.

Can anyone help me get on my way with refreshing the datasource? Basically what would seem the solution to me, is that the entire ViewController gets "refreshed", so it builds the entire CardView again, but I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I can just call the LoadView method on the NavigationController, which then calls the ViewWillLoad method for the ViewController in question. Then I can rebuild the CardView, remove the old CardView and add the new one to the Parent View.